# Best way to check a file content is changed or not with perl?

Tags: perl, checksum, textchanged, file-monitoring

There is a dynamic file which will be generated before my script executing.

```
my $file = a.txt;
```

Here i want to check:

```
(Is content of $file changed)? Do_something: Skip;
```

I'm looking for some solution as below:

- if ( if_modified( $file );

  --> But We need an initialization file and compare with the latest file while here we have only 1 file at a time.
- $monitor->watch( $file ); Is it able to do my task?
- I guess that using checksum is not needed because after that i also need to see if checksum result is changed or not.

Comment: "Has file changed" needs to specify since when. See also [Linux::Inotify2](http://p3rl.org/Linux::Inotify2).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Monitor
- https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Modified

And Linux-specififc:

- https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Inotify2

as mentioned by @choroba

Answer (score 2):

The Perl file operators and the [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function also tell you when a file was last changed (it's modification time) . The common approach is to check against some reference file, that is whether a file was changed later than the reference file, or to check when a file was changed relative to the script start.

## Get the time when a file was last modified

```
my $last_modified = (stat $filename)[9];

if( $last_modified >= $other_modified ) {
    # file changed since we last checked ...
    $other_modified = $last_modified;
};
```

## Check if a file was modified some days ago:

```
if( -M $filename > 5 ) {
    print "'$file' was modified at least 5 days ago\n";
};
```

## See also

[stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) , [the -M function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. But with this, how could we define the $other_modified to be used in if command? Is there any other solution to check the changing of content only?

Comment: You can initialize the value of `$other_modified` the same way: `$other_modified = (stat $filename)[9]` . You haven't told us enough about what your program needs to do , so we can't make good suggestions to your program logic flow.

Comment: With this initialzation, both of $other_modified and $last_modified will be initialized with the same value. It cause the if condition will always got true. Isn't it?

Comment: Both values will start out the same, but if time passes and the file gets modified in between, the values will differ, which is (I think) what the OP wants

Comment: Hmm i don't think so.  I think the if() condition always got true and code inside if{} will execute whenever this script is called.

Comment: ... unless of course the `if` condition is in a loop like `while( 1 ) { my $last_modified = (stat $filename)[9]; if( $filename >= $other_modified ) { print "Modified\n"; $other_modified=$last_modified }; sleep 60 }`